# Mapping an input value to a table of ranges in O(1) time

Tags: data-structures

I have a table of ranges and respective values. This table is generated in runtime, and may be small, or may be large. The ranges may be different in sizes. As an example:

```
[0 - 5]: a
[5 - 7]: b
[7 - 10]: c
[10 - 20]: d
```

I want to write a function that would return the value associated with a range given a value. It would check where in the table it would fit, then return the function associated with it. So basically:

```
f(2) == a
f(6) == b
etc.
```

The only way I can think of to do it is by linearly searching the table for where the input value fits. This would take O(n) time in the worst case, where n is the number of entries in the table. But I feel I can do better, especially since I want this function to be evaluated with hundreds or thousands of values and I don't want it to search all the time.

Is there a nice way to do this in O(1) time?

I am using python 3, but this question probably applies to any programming language. But python probably has some really nice syntactic sugar or data structure I can use, I hope

Also, this example uses integers. But would the solution change if I used real numbers?

Comment: will all the ranges be mutually exclusive? in other words can f(x) return an array instead of a single value. Your 4th example seems to suggest that

Comment: @ShihabShahriar I suspect the 4th example was supposed to be `[11 - 20]`

Comment: Binary search the range list. You can do that for integers, or for real numbers.

Comment: Yes they are mutually exclusive. I fixed my 4th example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure most appropriate for this problem, from what I can see, is an "Interval Tree"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Unfortunately, for real numbers it would seem that there's no way to perform an O(1) search, but O(log n + m) might be good enough, and in this case m would be effectively 1, as there are no overlapping intervals. Using a cache alongside this for multiple calls to the same interval might also be a good idea.

An intervaltree package can be found in pypi, here:

https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/

For non-real numbers, using a data structure like what was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53943134/1074358) allows you to do O(1) search at the cost of memory space.

Answer (score 2):

This would take o(n) space complexity.
while producing result store the "a or b or c or d" in the index ranges of table(like 0-5 or 5 -7)

```
arr=[a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c.....]
//if we print arr[2] we will get a and if we print arr[6] we will get b.
//intially storing will take o(n) once it is stored after that accessing will take o(1)
```

Or you can choose binary search which will take o(logn).

Comment: This works, but not for floats I guess, unless you use fixed point maybe